# How to find count of non-unique elements of array in php using stdin for input

Tags: php, arrays, stdout, stdin

following will be the input on STDIN.

The first line contains an integer, n, denoting the size of the numbers array.

Each line i of the n subsequent lines (where 0 ≤ i < n) contains an integer describing the value of numbers[i].

I want to print the integer denoting the number of non-unique values in numbers to STDOUT.

Sample Input

8
1
3
1
4
5
6
3
2

Sample Output

2

Comment: Question is unclear

Comment: I have not worked with STDIN and STDOUT before so dont know how to use them. I know array_unique can solve my problem but i dont know how to read data through stdin and store it in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `array_unique()` and `count()` functions:

```
$array = [];
while ($in = fread(STDIN, 1024)) { 
   $array = array_merge($array, explode("\n", $in)); 
}

array_shift($array);

echo (count($array) - count(array_unique($array)));
```

Comment: You need to remove the 8 from your array, because it is (like stated in the original problem) the length of the following integer sequence

Comment: Thanks for your support. Highly appreciated. The problem is I know hwo to do this with array_unique and count but dont know how to read the data through STDIN and store it in the $array.

Comment: use `array_shift($array);`  to remove first element from array @FlorianSchöffl

Comment: Try something like `while ($in = fread(STDIN, 1024)) { $array = array_merge($array, explode("\n", $in)); }` @JatinPurswani

Comment: Thanks Mith. But this will take the first value of 8 as well in the array i guess?

Comment: use array_shift($array); to remove first element from array @JatinPurswani

Comment: ahhhh..thanks alot Mith. I think I got it now. Can you please write the complete answer using your while loop . I'll mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks !. If it helps, up-vote/accept my answer :) @JatinPurswani

Comment: Can you please edit the answer and add your while loop to it to make it a complete answer?